# Testing function not returning values

Tags: go

I am running a test on this Go file. I'm confused why it is having problems working.

```
func TestMy(t *testing.T) {
    arr := map[string]string{
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
        RandomOwner(): RandomString(9),
    }
    ds := DataSourceStr{
        data: arr,
    }

    for k, v := range ds.data {
        //create dataset in datasource value method
        res, err := ds.Value(k)
        fmt.Println(res)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("%T does not implement Value method correctly, key %v not found", ds, k)
        }
        if res != v {
            t.Errorf("%T does not implement Value correctly. Expected %v but recieved %v: %v", ds, v, res, err)
        }
        return res, err
    }
}
```

It is returning this for the function above as an error,

```
/home/incompleteness_hewlbern/Documents/Code_Projects/Tests/nearmap/Private_test_golang/datasource/datasource_test.go:64:3: too many arguments to return
    have (interface {}, error)
    want ()
```

What have I made a mistake with, should I set the type in the function? How would I simply print things inside the function to test what is going on (it doesn't appear to show in the console).

Comment: Your function signature is `func TestMy(t *testing.T) {`. Note there are no return values there. So trying to return something will fail for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test functions don't return anything, test either passes or fails (doesn't meet the expectation) in which case `t.Errorf()` is used to signal a failure back to test driver executed by `go test ...`.

See https://golang.org/pkg/testing/

In your example function has signature of not returning anything: `func TestMy(t *testing.T) {` but tries to return `(interface {}, error)` hence the error. Changing last line of the loop `return res, err` to `return` to meet the signature of test function and fail early or remove that line completely (depending on desired test logic) will solve the problem.